# Using Redux Saga to get information from API

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm learning `Redux Saga` and trying to call an API everytime a component is rendered, and save the response of the API in the State object. I implemented the `Component` like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container } from "./styles";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as ratesActions from "../../stores/actions/rates";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    ratesActions.updateRate();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <div>
          <h1>Hi there!</h1>
        </div>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  rates: state.rates
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(ratesActions, dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(Main));
```

I want to everytime the `componentDidMount`, call the `updateRate()` action. This is the `updateRate()` action:

```
export function updateRate() {
  return {
    type: "ASYNC_RATE_UPDATED"
  };
}
```

This action is executed, because if I put a `console.log` in there, I can see it's working.

Then, I created my `sagas`:

```
import api from "../../services/api";
import { call, put, takeLatest, all } from "redux-saga/effects";

export function* updateRateAsync() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(api.get("public/rates/all"));

    yield put({
      type: "RATE_UPDATE_SUCCEEDED",
      response: response.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: "RATE_UPDATE_FAILED",
      message: error.message
    });
  }
}

export function* watchUpdateRates() {
  yield takeLatest("ASYNC_RATE_UPDATED", updateRateAsync);
}

export default function* root() {
  yield all([watchUpdateRates()]);
}
```

And my reducer:

```
export default function rates(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "RATE_UPDATE_SUCCEEDED":
      console.log(action.response[0]["exchange_rate"]);
      return {
        ...state,
        rates: {
          ves: action.response[0]["exchange_rate"],
          brl: null,
          ars: null,
          inr: null,
          zar: null
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

However, my `saga` won't listen to my `action`, and won't execute the `API` call. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what's wrong in your code.
You need to call `this.props.updateRate()` in componentDidMount instead of `ratesActions.updateRate()`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(ratesActions, dispatch);
```

Above line will bind all action in `rateActions` object to component's props.

### Update:

In response to your comment, State will be `null` since you have not defined one. data injected by redux connect will be available though props not by state. so you have to access rates like this `this.props.rates` in you component

Comment: I spent all afternoon searching for this problem! Thanks a lot! However, now the `Component` is not receiving the new state. The reducer is receiving from the `API` the response, passed by `action.response`. I'm returning a new object rates, however the state is null